# Magento 2.x knockoutjs dispaly data from observable Json Object

Tags: knockoutjs, json, magento2.3.5

to display data from observable array one can do:

**Component:**

```
myObject: ko.observableArray([{name: 'test'}]),
```

**Html:**

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: myObject">
     <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
</ul>
```

**Display:**

[image]

How can I Display a simple json object not an array like the above E.G:

**Component:**

```
myObject: ko.observable({name: 'test'}),
```

**HTML**

```
<li data-bind="text: myObject.name"></li>
```

**Display**
[image]

What am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template would need to look like this:

```html
<div data-bind="text: myObject().name"></div>
```

but after doing so you will run into the next issue. Because updating the observable values like:

```js
this.myObject().name = 'new value';
```

won't work. You would need to assign a whole new object to this.myObject. like f.e. by using

```js
var newObj = this.myObject();
newObj.name = 'new value';
this.myObject(newObj);
```

another possibility would be to not make the whole object an observable, but instead declaring the object properties as observables like:

```
myObject: {
  name: ko.observable('value')
},
```

so you can access the value in the template by using:

```html
<div data-bind="text: myObject.name()"></div>
```

or assigning new values to it by using:

```js
this.myObject.name('new value');
```

Comment: I think last option is good for me I don't have many properties. THX.